# Logs being flooded tsa.connection.tcpip-forward.forward-conn.io-complete

Tags: concourse

We are being flooded by this in the ATC logs over 2000 message per second.

```
{"timestamp":"1488987647.707217455","source":"tsa","message":"tsa.connection.tcpip-forward.forward-conn.closing-forwarded-tcpip","log_level":0,"data":{"remote":"172.16.4.61:55834","session":"6.3.75620"}}
{"timestamp":"1488987647.707637787","source":"tsa","message":"tsa.connection.tcpip-forward.forward-conn.waiting-for-tcpip-io","log_level":0,"data":{"remote":"172.16.4.61:55834","session":"6.3.75621"}}
{"timestamp":"1488987647.735419750","source":"tsa","message":"tsa.connection.tcpip-forward.forward-conn.io-complete","log_level":0,"data":{"remote":"172.16.4.61:55834","session":"6.3.75621"}}
{"timestamp":"1 488987647.735453606","source":"tsa","message":"tsa.connection.tcpip-forward.forward-conn.done-waiting","log_level":0,"data":{"remote":"172.16.4.61:55834","session":"6.3.75621"}}
```

We are running 8 workers and concourse 2.7.0 and we have over 9000 of TIME_WAIT connection.

Any ideas what and why this is happening ?

Comment: Are you seeing any weird behavior in concourse itself?

Comment: Yes I have long standing memory issue and also logs fill and logrotate can't handle the amount of logs

Comment: do you see any errors in logs? search for "log_level":2

Comment: some resource error, but not relevant